# Accessing root sibling file from React static site in AWS S3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

I have a React (Vite) app that I'm hosting from S3/CloudFront. It gets there via AWS CDK.

In the CDK (CloudFormation) process, I'm generating a deploy time JSON file `config.json) that I'm also putting into the same S3 bucket as the React app. See image below for what my bucket ends up looking like:

[image: s3 bucket structure]

What I would like to do is access the values in this `config.json` during runtime in my React app. In my running React App from CloudFront, It doesn't seem to be aware about the `config.json` file though:

[image]

To be clear, what I would like to do is do something like the following:

```js
// App.tsx

import * as config from "./config.json"

fetch(config.url, ....)
```

**Note:** Cloudfront does have privelages for all files in this bucket:

```js
siteBucket.addToResourcePolicy(
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        actions: ["s3:GetObject"],
        resources: [siteBucket.arnForObjects("*")],
        principals: [
          new iam.CanonicalUserPrincipal(
            cloudfrontOAI.cloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityS3CanonicalUserId
          ),
        ],
      })
    );
    new CfnOutput(this, "Bucket", { value: siteBucket.bucketName });
```

Comment: Just found https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/deploy-static-react-app-s3-refreshing-json-data-siva-rajan/ which looks very related to what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/deploy-static-react-app-s3-refreshing-json-data-siva-rajan/) article which outlined a similar pattern.

By fetching the file on mount, I can read the appropriate config that's generated at deploy time at the top level of the React app:

```js
// App.tsx

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/config.json")
      .then(function (res) {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(function (data) {
        setData(data);
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err, " error");
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)</div>
  );
}
```